# Select Progressive larger record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using T-SQL i have a query that pulls the following information from a range of tables.  From this information i then need to select the rows where the runs get progressively larger.

```
Runs    Name         Opposition              Ground          Date       RN
4   Wickramanayake  Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   1
51  Mahoney         Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   2
157 Beghin          Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   3
10  Olsen           Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   4
9   Thomson         Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   5
12  Chitongo        Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   6
40  McKenzie        Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   7
1   Wall            Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   8
0   Duncraft        Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   9
0   Beghin          Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   10
0   Olsen           Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   11
0   Thomson         Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   12
0   Chitongo        Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   13
0   McKenzie        Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   14
0   Hinds           Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   15
0   Wall            Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   16
0   Brungar         Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   17
0   Duncraft        Ellerslie          Devonport Domain 25-26/11/2016   18
2   Beghin          Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   19
0   Wickramanayake  Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   20
7   Olsen           Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   21
15  Thomson         Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   22
0   Hinds           Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   23
34  Hira            Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   24
0   Wall            Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   25
5   Brungar         Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   26
8   Duncraft        Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   27
0   Strain          Suburbs New Lynn    Vauxhall Road   7/10/2017   28
74  Beghin          Ellerslie           Vauxhall Road   14/10/2017  29
```

So the result set would (using this data) only contain the first three rows because the first highest runs is 4, and then the next highest is 51. then the next highest is 157. And since there is no other runs higher than 157 there would be no more records.

I hope this makes sense..I do like an SQL challenge, but sometimes i struggle.. lol

Comment: So you just need to find the highest Runs and limit your rows by RN up to that value?

Comment: If the second row instead of runs=51 had runs=3, shoult it be selected or not?

Comment: If you added a row to the end with 999 runs, should you return 4 rows *(RN's `1, 2, 3, 30`)*, or 30 rows?

Comment: Not clear to me

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis if the second row was 3 then it shouldn't be selected.

Comment: @MatBailie yes, bang on with that. It will return 1,2,3,30.  Only to select the value if it is bigger than the last biggest value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am interpreting this as starting from the first row, get subsequent rows that are increasing in value.  The fact that these are the first three rows in the example is a coincidence.

If I understand correctly, you want rows that define the cumulative maximum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(runs) over (order by rn) as cumalative_runs
      from t
     ) t
where cumulative_runs = runs;
```

Comment: You sir are a champion and a scholar.. works like an absolute charm